# Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error: Expected end_of_string but found id in

Tags: syntax, liquid

i'm using this line of code

```
<img data-animate="zoomIn" srcset="{{ 'device1.png' | asset_path | magick:resize:549x395 magick:quality:100 }} 1024w, {{ 'device1.png' | asset_path | magick:resize:280x201magick:quality:100 }} 640w" src="{{ 'device1.png' | asset_path | magick:resize:549x395 magick:quality:100 }}" alt="Mac" style="width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;">
```

but i'm getting a liquid error like this

> Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error: Expected end_of_string but found
>   id in "{{ 'device1.png' | asset_path | magick:resize:549x395
>   magick:quality

Can you help me with the right syntax of this ?

Thanks in advance.
Carlos Vieira

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Running into the same kind of issue.

Comment: Sorry, not yet... having the same issue for several images...

Comment: @Taylor: https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/liquid-warning-liquid-syntax-error-expected-end-of-string-but-found-id-in/2854

Comment: I think I solved this by replacing `|` with `or`

Comment: sorry but the issue is the same "Expected end_of_string but found id in "{{ 'device1.png' or asset_path or magick:resize:549x395"

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue. It seems a newer version of Liquid doesn't expect the pipe. I was able to fix it by removing the pipe altogether. Here was my issue:

Error: `{% for post in site.posts | limit: 5 %}`

Fixed: `{% for post in site.posts limit: 5 %}`

This page may help with proper liquid syntax http://jekyll.tips/jekyll-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Thanks, just remove the pipe, also worked for me for the current version of liquid

Comment: I had the opposite problem, the warning/error got caused by a missing pipe and I got it fixed by adding in the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue today with the following code:

```
{%- if title_case contains ' ' -%}
  {%- assign all_strings = title_case | split: ' ' -%}
  {%- assign the_string = '' -%}
  {%- for str in all_strings -%}
      {% assign new_string = str | capitalize %}
  {% assign the_string = the_string | append: new_string | append: ' ' %}
  {%- endfor -%}
  {%- assign title_case = the_string | strip-%}
{%- endif -%}
{{ title _case }}
```

The problem was an extra space in the word 'title_case' - because it was a space followed by an underscore, Shopify interpreted it as an id!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/expected-end-of-string-but-found-pipe/1527):

> Sorting a for loop directly doesn’t generally work in my experience.

**Workaround:** use `assign` & apply sort to that array first, then use the sorted array in the for loop as below:

```
{% assign sortedPosts = site.posts | sort: 'last_modified_at' %}

{% for post in sortedPosts %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -3):

The right answer is:

First use this plugin:

```
    require "jekyll-assets"

class Jekyll::ImagePath < Jekyll::Assets::Liquid::Tag

  def initialize(tag, args, tokens)
    super("img", args, tokens)
  end

  private
  def build_html(args, sprockets, asset, path = get_path(sprockets, asset))
      path
  end

end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('image_path', Jekyll::ImagePath)
```

then in image use

```
src="{% image_path 'customize-template-image.png' magick:resize: 549x375 magick:quality:100 %}"
```

This would fix for sure